# Counting pixels using recursion

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I have a problem where I need to count the number of 1's in a 2D array that is randomly generated. First the user puts in the size of the 2D array through the command line arguments, and then the user puts in the coordinates to see if there are 1's in the coordinates he put in. If the coordinate happen to land in 0, it is supposed to return 0. Otherwise if the inputted coordinate lands on a 1, then I am supposed to recursively check up, top right, right, bottom right, bottom, bottom left, left, and top left.

The main problem I am having is that I don't know if I can even read in one 1 from the array. I have no idea what to put into my recursive method parameters. I have my **array pointer**, **xcoord**, **ycoord** which are what the user puts in and **row** and **col** which are supposed to be command line arguments.

I think everything else works, but I could be wrong. I tried this recursive formula.

```
if(arr[row][col] == 1)
{
     recursive(arr, xcoord-1, ycoord, row, col);
     blobsize = blobsize + 1;
     //more recursive things down here...
}
```

to check up but it didn't do anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int recursive(int **arr, int xcoord, int ycoord, int row, int col);//What are the arguments for the recursive function?

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;//counters
    int j;//counters
    int xcoord;//x coordinate input
    int ycoord;//y coordinate input

    //random number generator thing idk lol
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    int row = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);//ROW from command line arguments (1st number)
    int col = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);//COL from command line arguments (2nd number)

    int *arrStorage = malloc(row * col * sizeof(int));//dynamically allocating memory for 2d array
    int **arr = malloc(row * sizeof(int*));       //pointer to pointer to array or whatever

    //intializing array
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
            arr[i] = arrStorage + col * i;
    }

    //printing out 2d array
        for (i = 0; i <  row; i++)
        {
           for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
           {
              arr[i][j] = rand() % 2;
              printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
           }

           printf("\n");
        }

    printf(" ");

    //Exit the function when non number is entered
    //Otherwise continue
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter coordinate i,j (Non numeric to quit) \n");    

        if(1!=scanf("%d", &xcoord) || 1!=scanf("%d", &ycoord))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        printf("Blob size: %d\n", recursive(arr, xcoord, ycoord, row, col));
    }

    free(arr[0]);
    free(arr);

}

int recursive(int **arr, int xcoord, int ycoord, int row, int col)
{
    int blobsize = 0;

    //This is outside the bounds (BASE CASE)
    if(xcoord > row && ycoord > col)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    //If the selected xcoord & ycoord is 0
    if(arr[xcoord][ycoord] == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        if((arr[xcoord][ycoord]==1))
        {
            //blobsize = blobsize + 1;
            //recursive(arr, xcoord - 1, ycoord, row, col);

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    return blobsize;

}
```

Thanks if you can help

EDIT: Fixed one critical part. Now to die over figuring out the recursion part.

Comment: I assume this is a homework assignment, right? Because Moore neighborhood is a weird thing to traverse recursively.

Comment: What are some of the typical values used for `row` and `col`?

Comment: `printf("%d\t", rand() % 2);` prints a number but that is not assigned to `arr[i][j]`.  Was that intended?

Comment: @Kovalainen yeah lol

Comment: Yes, the memory for the 2D array is yet to be populated.  Try `printf("%d\t", rand() % 2);` --> `arr[i][j] = rand() % 2; printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);`

Comment: @chux I am supposed to use random number generator to fill in the 2D array. But like you mentioned I don't think I am using those randomly generated number in the arr[i][j]. I was afraid I was doing that

EDIT: It compiles and I think it's filling the 2d array with 0's or 1's thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP was printing a random number, yet not assigning the number to the array.

Simply assign the value and then print.

```
// printf("%d\t", rand() % 2);
arr[i][j] = rand() % 2;
printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
```

Comment: OT issue: Consider `int *arrStorage = malloc(row * col * sizeof(int));` --> `int *arrStorage = malloc(sizeof *arrStorage * row * col);`.  Easier to code correctly, review and maintain.  Also a benefit for extreme cases: With _very large_ arrays, does not overflow some `int` math that can work with `size_t` math.